# Tips for my IF-statments and a calculation

Tags: c++

I need som help with my code! For me its looks okey but it doesn't work. I have tried and searched but i can't figure out whats wrong.

I also need help with another calculation. I if type in 2 and 4, it should calculate 2*2+3*3+4*4. And if i type 1 and 3 it should be 1*1+2*2+3*3, i hope you understand!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void sort(float & tal1, float & tal2);

int main() {
    float x, y;
    int sum, i, a, m, val;
    cout << "Give to numbers: " << endl;
    cout << "Type one number \n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Type another number \n";
    cin >> y;
    if (x > y) {
        sort(x, y);
    }
    cout << x << " och " << y << endl;
    cout << "Choose between a and m! " << endl;
    cin >> val;
    if (val == 'a') {
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
            sum += i;
        cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    } else if (val == 'm') {
        sum = 1;
        for (int i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
            sum *= i;
            cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
        }
    }
}

void sort(float & tal1, float & tal2) {
    float temp = tal1;
    tal1 = tal2;
    tal2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Is the result wrong? Does it throw an exception? Not compile? More info will lead to better answers :)

Comment: `it doesn't work`  You need to be more specific.  Which line(s) do not "work"?

Comment: It says "sum" where it should say "product" in several places. You haven't been copying and pasting, have you? The `float` inputs look a bit iffy, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
for( int i = x ; i <= y ; i++ ){

        sum +=i;
        cout << "Sum = "<< sum <<endl;
    }
```

this should be changed to

```
for( int i = x ; i <= y ; i++ ){

        sum +=(i*i);
        cout << "Sum = "<< sum <<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to modify the else branch that checks if val is "m"

```
else if (val == 'm')
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
    {
        sum += i*i;
        cout << "Sum = "<<sum<<endl;
    } 

}
```